# Set the selected item in a select list based on template value

Tags: html, meteor, handlebars.js

How can you correctly pre-populate a select control with the current value from the template?

I have a simple form to edit a record where the values for the selected record are pre-populated when the form is shown. A bit like this:

```
<input type="text" id="project_name_edit" value="{{selected_name}}">
```

But where I am using a select control I need to be able to interogate the template value and conditionally set the `selected='selected'` property for the correct option.

```
<select id="project_status_edit" value="{{selected_status}}">
      <option>GOOD</option>
      <option>BAD</option>
      <option>UGLY</option>
</select>
```

handlesbars.js offers the #IF helper but this only gives truthy or falsy.

I could probably hack this in various way but this seems like a scenario where there would be a standard solution.

Comment: I would probably use a script helper on the `select` to add `selected` to the appropriate `option`, or `if` within each `option`. You could also precompile the `select` and `option`s and depict which is the `option selected` (I think). I don't know there's a construct that handles this in plain handlebars templating directly or elegantly.

Comment: Using `#if` (or another helper) was my first thought but I am not aware of how to get the actual value - is it possible / do you have an example? Pre-compiling would work but then this rather steps outside of the structure and kind of removes the benefit of a template and ideally I want to avoid this sort of path.

Comment: You mean `<option{{#if selected_status == 'this option'}} selected{{/if}}>this option</option>`?

Comment: Yes, except that gives: ...`Error: Parse error, if selected_status == 'GOOD'}} selected{
-------------------------------------------------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID'`

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I don't think you can then with helpers or precompilation. I was thinking of Smarty templates and the Handlebars source code doesn't imply that conditionals aren't supported.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('selected', function(foo, bar) {
  return foo == bar ? ' selected' : '';
});
```

Which you can then call with:

```
<select id="project_status_edit">
  <option{{selected foo "GOOD"}}>GOOD</option>
  <option{{selected foo "BAD"}}>BAD</option>
  <option{{selected foo "UGLY"}}>UGLY</option>
</select>
```

Using:

```
{"foo":"UGLY"}
```

Try it here:

http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Although it doesn't appear to let me save it. `:(`

Comment: Or you could pull handlebars.js off a CDN and jsfiddle it: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w2wyU/1/

Comment: I have a bunch bookmarked in my profile 'cuz I got tired of tracking down all the various bits of JS and CSS all the time.

Answer (score 11):

The selected answer doesn't work anymore. It's an old question but I had a hard time figuring this simple thing out. Here's my solution:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('selected', function(key, value){
       return key == value? {selected:'selected'}: '';
});
```

In present version of meteor, we can't set HTML attributes without value, and meteor doesn't allow using {{#if}} either. But the objects passed to the helper are converted into key=value pairs and injected.

**UPDATE**

Use `UI.registerHelper` instead of `Handlebars.registerHelper` in new (> 0.8) versions of meteor since Handlebars namespace is depreciated (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#handlebars-namespace-deprecated).

Comment: Now that we're post-Blaze you can use UI.registerHelper instead of Handlebars.registerHelper.

Comment: It's an old comment. I should've written the version number up there.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following in my project (in case someone needs it :)

```
  <select class="form-control" id="maritalStatusList" >
      <option {{selectedMaritalStatus  "Single"}}> Single</option>
      <option {{selectedMaritalStatus  "Married"}}> Married</option>
  </select>
```

and

```
Template.editApplicant.helpers({
   selectedMaritalStatus: function(key){
      return key == this.maritalStatus ? 'selected' : '';
   }
});
```

"this.maritalStatus" gets the Marital Status from the current document (Applicant).

Use the following code, to save the value in the database

```
maritalStatus: $('#maritalStatusList').val()
```

Thanks for you all..

Answer (score 1):

I had almost an identical problem, but values I was passing were numbers and I believe I have a cleaner solution for that specific case, that is without depending on Handlebars magic.

In the template:

```
<select name="button-style" id="button-style" _val="{{button_style}}">
    <option value="1">Primary Style</option>
    <option value="2">Secondary Style</option>
</select>
```

you basically pass the number of the attribute you want selected with _val. This is useful only in a case where each option has a consecutive numerical value. Also note, if you name this attribute 'value', it will get overwritten/ignored by the default, which selects first option.

Now in the .rendered callback in your JS file:

```
Template.templateName.rendered = () ->
    var btn_style = $('#button-style').attr('_val')
    $('#button-style option:nth-child(' + btn_style + ')').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

This simply selects the 'nth' option in this select field which corresponds to the value we want.

Answer (score 1):

I made this function. Adapt to your case

```
selectedOption=function(){
        selectedOpt=document.getElementById("yourTagId_Select");
        var att = document.createAttribute("selected");
        att.value = "selected";
        idObj=Session.get("idObj");
        var lib = yourCollection.find({'column._id':idObj}).fetch();      
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedOpt.length; i++) {
             if (selectedOpt[i].value==lib._id._str){               
                return selectedOpt[i].setAttributeNode(att);
            }
        };


    }
```

After call your function

selectedOption();