# CI active navigation item

Tags: php, codeigniter

In a site navigation bar, I have some logic that determines which page the user is currently viewing, and gives that menu-item an `.active` class.

The code I came up with does work, though it doesn't feel very elegant. Can you think of a way to do this better? How could I move the logic out of the view and into the controller? How can I stop repeating myself?

**The controller:**

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view ($page = 'home') {

        if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            show_404();

        $data['active'] = $page;

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}

?>
```

**The view:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php echo($active=='home')?'active':''; ?>"><a href="./">blog</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($active=='about')?'active':''; ?>"><a href="about">about</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($active=='projects')?'active':''; ?>"><a href="projects">projects</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($active=='lab')?'active':''; ?>"><a href="lab">lab</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo($active=='contact')?'active':''; ?>"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Shall I create a new question on CR? Or will someone move this question?

Comment: Personally, what you've got is not a bid deal. There are possibly more "elegant" ways of doing it (switch in the PHP to a specific variable? `onload` Javascript?). Another way could be to build the menu lists dynamically and within that set the value. One half dozen...

Comment: I wouldn't use JS for this. Perhaps you're right though; it may not be so ugly after all.

Comment: Using JS has it's pros and cons. One thing I would suggest is get rid of the useless ternaries; just `<?php if ($active=='whatever') echo 'active';?>`, there's no reason to echo a blank space and an `if` is more descriptive. Also, you could use a PHP template function as I demonstrate [with this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124234/set-the-selected-item-in-a-select-list-based-on-template-value/12124619#12124619) with Handlebars (which is only demonstrate you could do it with a specially built function, not suggest you use Handlebars for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe more elegant ?

```
    function is_active($item) {
        return strpos(uri_string(), $item)!==FALSE ? 'active':'';
    }


    <li class="<?=is_active('blog')?>"><a href="./">blog</a></li>
```

This way depend of complexity of your uris.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with CSS. E.g. if you're on the 'about' page, its body tag would be `<body id="about">`. Your CSS:

```
#about .nav li.about, #contact .nav li.contact, /* etc */ { color: red; }
```

This implies each of your .nav li's have a class name relevant to it (in this case "about"). There would be some repetition in your CSS file (though it's just a matter of comma delimiting all li class names before the property declarations), but the view would be kept clean.